# Get a C# Class Library to have WCF services?

Tags: c#, wcf

How can I get a C# class library to have WCF services? I have WCF services added in there, just that I can't get it to run since it complains that the project type of Class library cannot be set as startup. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the WCF service implementation in your class library needs to be **hosted** somewhere - either in IIS (like the legacy ASMX web services), or you can self-host.

See MSDN for [How to host a WCF service in a managed application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) (self-hosting) or [How to host a service in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx).

In addition, Visual Studio 2008 also has a "generic" service host application in its Common7/IDE folder, called "WcfSvcHost.exe". See the [MSDN docs on that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552363.aspx). You can set up your Visual Studio class library project to automatically launch this service host app to host your service, so you can test it.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, a dll isn't usually "executed" as such. There *are* hosts for dlls (COM+, for example), but typically you would have either an exe (perhaps a service) or IIS (or another web-server) act as the host process. For an example, [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx).

For re-use purposes it is fine to have the "real" code in the dll, and have the host exe a 5-liner that just calls into the dll (allowing you to use the dll in other scenarios).